# How can a user access the repository of application with help of an empty Shell component?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was going through [IBM Worklight - Shell documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/features/shell/), which mentions the following:

> A shell can be distributed empty to the user who will then access a
>   repository of applications stored on the Server.

- How can an empty shell be distributed to the user (I assume this not
  the developer, but an application user)?
- How can a user access the repository of applications with help of
  an empty Shell component? Is it related to IBM AppCenter?

Can someone help me in getting the concept behind this?

Answer (score 0):

> How can an empty shell be distributed to the user (I assume this not
>   the developer, but an application user)?

A Shell is made up of a "regular" Worklight project; it's still a project and an application with an environment, so the end result is still for example an Android or iOS application that you install on a device, thus you basically get "an empty shell that can be distributed to the user", like any other application.

> How can a user access the repository of applications with help of an
>   empty Shell component? Is it related to IBM AppCenter?

That is a mystery to me as well.
It is not related to Application Center.